# Is infinite recursion possible with CSS cross-fade()?

Tags: css, image, cross-fade

I've noticed in the W3C docs that [cross-fade()](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#funcdef-cross-fade) is defined as follows:

```
cross-fade() = cross-fade( <cf-mixing-image> , <cf-final-image>? )
```

where

```
<cf-mixing-image> = <percentage>? && <image>
<cf-final-image> = <image> | <color>
```

Now, in the same document, click on the link for [`<image>`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#typedef-image) and this is defined as:

```
<image> = <url> | <cross-fade()> | <gradient>
```

In other words, `cross-fade()` (via `<image>`) can be recursively defined an infinite number of times; here is the `n = 3` (3 nested `cross-fade()` instances) case:

```
background: cross-fade(50% cross-fade(40% cross-fade(60% cross-fade(10% url('http://www.randomimage.com/image.png'), white), blue), red), green);
```

*Can this function be recursively defined an infinite number of times, and if so, how would an increasing number of nested cross-fade() statements affect performance?*

Comment: try it out, you can use a JS loop to add crossfades.......